# hls replace type of the files after the encode?

Tags: ffmpeg

i am using ffmpeg to encode mp4 files to hls for streaming with this script

```
for file in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 \
    -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 \
    -s:v:0 640x360 -crf:v:0 16 \
    -s:v:1 1280x720 -crf:v:1 20 \
    -s:v:2 1920x1080 -c:v:2 copy -c:a copy \
    -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0,name:360p v:1,a:1,name:720p v:2,a:2,name:1080p" \
    -preset fast -hls_allow_cache 1 -threads 0 -f hls -hls_playlist_type vod -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 3 \
    -hls_flags independent_segments -master_pl_name "${file%.mp4}".m3u8 \
    -hls_segment_filename ./"${file%.mp4}"-%v/segment_%03d.ts ./"${file%.mp4}"-%v/play.m3u8 ; done
```

and i want after the encode to make all the .ts files renamed with random types .jpg .txt etc..

```
#EXTINF:3.003000,
segment_000.jpg
#EXTINF:3.211533,
segment_001.css
#EXTINF:3.336667,
segment_002.html
#EXTINF:3.128133,
segment_003.srt
#EXTINF:2.711033,
segment_004.vtt
#EXTINF:6.631633,
segment_005.txt
```

the hls is working after i rename all this manual is any easy way after the encode to run a bash or a script to rename all the .ts files and the insite of m3u8??